# Weak generators of the right-bounded derived category of a finite-dimensional algebra

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

The setup:

- Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra over some field $k$.
- Let $\mathcal{B} = Hot^-(Proj A)$ denote the homotopy category of cochain complexes of (possibly infinitely generated) projective right $A$-modules which are bounded from the right. This category can be identified with the right-bounded derived category $D^-(Mod A)$ of $A$-modules.
- Let $\mathcal{C} = Hot^-(proj A)$ denote the full subcategory of $\mathcal{B}$ given by right-bounded complexes of *finitely generated* projective $A$-modules. In different terms, this category corresponds to the right-bounded derived category
  $D^-(mod A)$ of finitely generated $A$-modules.
- Let $P$ be a perfect object of $\mathcal{B}$, that is, a bounded complex of finitely generated projective right $A$-modules. 
  Assume also that $P$ is a **weak generator** of the small category $\mathcal{C}$, so for any object $X \in \mathcal{C}$  there is some integer $m$ and some non-zero morphism $P \to X[m]$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

My question:

> Is $P$ already a weak generator of the big category $\mathcal{B}$?

Some background:

1. By a result of Jeremy Rickard, the answer is affirmative if $P$ is a partial tilting complex, that is, if $Hom_{\mathcal{B}}(P,P[n])=0$ for any non-zero integer $n$.

Reference:
Proposition 5.4 in 
*Rickard, Jeremy*, [**Morita theory for derived categories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-39.3.436), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 39, No. 3, 436-456 (1989). [ZBL0642.16034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0642.16034).

2. By a result of Bruno J. Müller, any projective $A$-module is a (possibly infinite) direct sum of finitely generated projective $A$-modules.

Reference: 
*Müller, Bruno J.*, On semi-perfect rings, Mathematical Report No. 19, Vol. 1. Hamilton, Ont.: McMaster University, Department of Mathematics. 11 p. (1969). [ZBL0226.16026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0226.16026).

3. At least, $P$ is a weak generator of the homotopy category of complexes of projective $A$-modules which have finitely generated cohomology at each degree.

Any comments and any input will be very appreciated.

Comment: Given the rather advanced nature of this question, I think it would receive more attention on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). If you agree, you can click `flag`>`in need of moderator intervention` and request that a moderator migrate the question to MathOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have posted a slightly extended version of the question on MathOverflow.